# Error while deploying the react app on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, material-ui

While deploying the `react app` in Heroku I am getting below error. I have deleted `package-lock.json` and did an npm install again, but again I am getting the same error. Could someone please advise on how can I resolve the error ?

Following are the dependencies installed :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tweet-embed": "^2.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.20.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Logs from Heroku app:

```
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.15.1...
       Using default npm version: 8.11.0
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
       npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
       npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16" from react-scripts@5.0.1
       npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
       npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
       npm ERR!   16 more (@mui/utils, react-router-dom, @emotion/react, ...)
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
       npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
       npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
       npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.MrETS/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add npm --legacy-peer-deps in the heroku

Comment: Thank you, where do I need to add in Heroku ? In which screen/ tab ?

Comment: try to add heroku:postbuild in your package.json

Comment: Should I add like the below : 
``"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:server": "node src/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm --legacy-peer-deps"
  } ``

Answer (score 0):

adding "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions", and "heroku-postbuild": "npm install" to the package.json file as follow, helped me through this problem

```json
"scripts": {    "start": "react-scripts start",
                "build": "react-scripts build",
                "test": "react-scripts test", 
                "eject": "react-scripts eject",     
                "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
                "heroku-postbuild": "npm install"   }
```